# How can I join these 25 INSERT queries into just one?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, sql-insert, sql-optimization

I have a web-based system that reads a sheet of an excel file (each sheet uploaded is 6 rows-5 columns) like this:

[image]

Below is the code I'm using (for demonstration purposes I've set static values for the $entry but its real code would be for example `$entry1=$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A2')->getValue();`

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","view");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$entry1 = 1;
$entry2 = 2;
$entry3 = 3;
$entry4 = 4;
$entry5 = 5;
$entry6 = 1;
$entry7 = 2;
$entry8 = 0;
$entry9 = 4;
$entry10 = 0;
$entry11 = 0;
$entry12 = 2;
$entry13 = 3;
$entry14 = 4;
$entry15 = 0;
$entry16 = 1;
$entry17 = 2;
$entry18 = 0;
$entry19 = 0;
$entry20 = 5;
$entry21 = 1;
$entry22 = 0;
$entry23 = 3;
$entry24 = 0;
$entry25 = 5;

if($entry1 != 0 || !empty($entry1))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry1','$entry1')");
}
if($entry2 != 0 || !empty($entry2))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry2','$entry2')");
}
if($entry3 != 0 || !empty($entry3))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry3','$entry3')");
}
if($entry4 != 0 || !empty($entry4))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry4','$entry4')");
}
if($entry5 != 0 || !empty($entry5))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry5','$entry5')");
}
if($entry6 != 0 || !empty($entry6))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry6','$entry6')");
}
if($entry7 != 0 || !empty($entry7))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry7','$entry7')");
}
if($entry8 != 0 || !empty($entry8))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry8','$entry8')");
}
if($entry9 != 0 || !empty($entry9))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry9','$entry9')");
}
if($entry10 != 0 || !empty($entry10))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry10','$entry10')");
}
if($entry11 != 0 || !empty($entry11))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry11','$entry11')");
}
if($entry12 != 0 || !empty($entry12))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry12','$entry12')");
}
if($entry13 != 0 || !empty($entry13))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry13','$entry13')");
}
if($entry14 != 0 || !empty($entry14))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry14','$entry14')");
}
if($entry15 != 0 || !empty($entry15))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry15','$entry15')");
}
if($entry16 != 0 || !empty($entry16))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry16','$entry16')");
}
if($entry17 != 0 || !empty($entry17))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry17','$entry17')");
}
if($entry18 != 0 || !empty($entry18))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry18','$entry18')");
}
if($entry19 != 0 || !empty($entry19))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry19','$entry19')");
}
if($entry20 != 0 || !empty($entry20))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry20','$entry20')");
}
if($entry21 != 0 || !empty($entry21))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry21','$entry21')");
}
if($entry22 != 0 || !empty($entry22))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry22','$entry22')");
}
if($entry23 != 0 || !empty($entry23))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry23','$entry23')");
}
if($entry24 != 0 || !empty($entry24))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry24','$entry24')");
}
if($entry25 != 0 || !empty($entry25))
{   
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES('1','entry25','$entry25')");
}
}
?>
```

I do have a couple of questions:

1. Would it be possible to have all of these statements into one?
2. Are there any significant performance changes when doing one big query rather than multiple ones?

Comment: Yes and yes. You can insert multiple sets of data in one statement, check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: It's a little tricky though, since they aren't static, I can't make a static sql query. I can't join variables holding these `('1','entry1','$entry1')` together into one statement as I'll have problems placing the commas. One solution I found however, was to ALLOW 0s so that I can create a static query THEN delete all of the rows with 0 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a single SQL statement. It would work like this. You can string together as many sets of (val, val, val) as you want. (There's a limit on the string length of the overall query, but it's quite large in MySQL).

```
INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES
      ('1','entry1','$entry1'),
      ('1','entry2','$entry2'),
      ('1','entry3','$entry3')
```

If you're inserting stuff into an InnoDB table, you get quite a lot of performance boost by doing this when your connection is in autocommit mode. That's because you commit all the rows in the insert together, and commit has an overhead.

**Edit**
In php, if you have an array $values, each element of which contains a text string like `(1,'val','val')`  you can use this code to create your query string.

```
$sqlstart = 'INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES ';
$sql = sqlstart . implode(',' , $values);
```

This puts commas *between* but not after the elements of the $values array. [`implode()` is made for this kind of purpose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

So, your code might look like this:

```
$values = array();  /* make an empty array */
if ($entry1 != 0 || !empty($entry1)) {
   $values[] = "('1','entry1','$entry1')";  /* append to array */
}
if ($entry2 != 0 || !empty($entry2)) {
   $values[] = "('1','entry2','$entry2')";
}
/* etc etc for the rest of your $entry values */
$sqlstart = 'INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES ';
$sql = sqlstart . implode(',' , $values);
```

(Please beware of SQL insertion exploits).

Comment: I did try this path, however, I had troubles with the commas. If I tried making $statement1 = ('1','entry1','$entry1'); and have those $statements echo'ed out into the sql query. I can't place the commas properly since the values aren't static.

Comment: If I tried to create a query that looks like this `INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,vale) VALUES $statement1,$statement2` and so on I would get in trouble with the commas as I can have two commas when a $statement doesn't exist since it's 0 or doesn't have a value.

Comment: @CarlEren I don't understand the problem, you can build your single sql statement using the same logic you have now for multiple statements.

Comment: I don't know how to put the commas to separate them since the values aren't static. If for example I have `$statement1=('1','entry1','$entry1'); $statement2=('1','entry2','$entry2');` then echo it out into this query `INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES $statement1 $statement2` but that's the problem, I don't know how to put the commas as I can't possible know which one has values. Keep in mind that this is a system that is used to upload those spreadsheets to the database and if I tried to upload a different spreadsheet with fewer values, my old queries won't make it.

Comment: If I tried to create this query `"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES $statement1,$statement2";` what would happen if the second spreadsheet I upload doesn't have an $entry2? that would mean `"INSERT INTO viewer(base_id,name,value) VALUES $statement1,";` since $statement2 would be declared IF $entry2 has a value.

Comment: Good answer, although the comma I was pertaining to was the comma after the ('1','entry1','$entry1')`,` <--- that one

Comment: That very comma is the one that won't be placed at the end of the string when you use `implode()` .

Comment: Oh that settles it then :D, Great answer.